# how to display image automatically in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to display image automatically when form open not when button press or any other event

How to achieve this target in oracle forms 11g?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what image  it is, so I'll presume that there's a data block which fetches images from the database.

In order not to do anything, but make that image appear, create a `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger which looks like this:

```
go_block('block_that_contains_the_image');
execute_query;
```

Comment: Bravo Littlefoot, I believe that, in this way, you'll be the first holder of `oracleforms` badge.

Comment: Heh, @Barbaros, I'm still *miles away* from it (especially because not so many people use Forms nowadays, so there aren't many questions to be answered either), but thank you for believing in me :)